# Pivot SQL table to N columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pivot, dynamic-sql

I have a table t1 with 3 columns showing quantity sold per product per day, products in the table are dynamic, new products are added in the table later (A,B,C, ...).
I need to pivot the table t1 to {date, the quantity of product A sold, the quantity of product B sold, the quantity of product C sold, and so on..}

I can write a query with a case statement if products are fixed, that is case A, B, C, but I need a dynamic solution.

```
---------------
-- INPUT DATA
-- table t1
-- date     product_name   quantity_sold
-- 1/1/2013    A           100
-- 1/1/2013    B           200
-- 1/1/2013    C           300
-- 1/2/2013    A           101
-- 1/2/2013    C           301
-- 1/3/2013    A           102
-- 1/3/2013    B           202
-- 1/3/2013    C           302


-- DESIRED OUTPUT
-- date     qty_prod_a  qty_prod_b  qty_prod_c
-- 1/1/2013  100        200         300
-- 1/2/2013  101        0           301
-- 1/3/2013  102        202         302
```

Comment: 'but I need a dynamic solution.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by P.Salmon, you need dynamic sql to achieve that. This means dynamically building the query string, then executing it.

Here is a typical solution:

```
set @q = null;
select
    group_concat(distinct
        concat(
            'sum(case when product_name = ''', 
            product_name, 
            ''' then quantity_sold else 0 end) as `qty_prod_', 
            lower(product_name),
            '`'
        )
) into @q
from t1;

set @q = concat(
    'select 
        date,
        ', @q, '
    from t1
    group by date
    order by date'
);

prepare stmt from @q;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=df25abe7539ebe02f80469168c381c14)**:

```
date       | qty_prod_a | qty_prod_b | qty_prod_c
:--------- | ---------: | ---------: | ---------:
2013-01-01 |        100 |        200 |        300
2013-01-02 |        101 |          0 |        301
2013-01-03 |        102 |        202 |        302
```

Comment: This is hacky... Make sure your product names don't contain blanks or single quotes. This would basically screw things up. You might also run into problems, if your number of products gets too big.
While this solution might work correctly for the test data, i strongly discourage to use it for production code.

Comment: @JochenReinhardt: as per my understanding, dynamic SQL is actually what the OP asked for. I suggest that you would better comment on the question itself than downvoting the answer that, as far as concerned, gives the correct technique for what was required.

Comment: Your suggested solution has a couple of flaws. Thus the down vote. Your concatenation will create incorrect results for product names like `prod a` or `GMB's`

Comment: The idea behind to have a dynamic query is to perform data analysis and data visualization. @JochenReinhard yes even I would not recommended to use it in production environment

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a good idea to have a dynamic count of columns.

Instead try grouping and summing your original data.

```sql
select date, product_name, sum(quantity_sold) 
from t1 
group by date, product_name;
```

This will not actually give you a pivoted table, but that's the way to go with SQL, IMHO.

Comment: Yes Jochen the group by is the optimized & sql way to do it, I am already know it, I am specifically looking for dynamic solution.

Comment: I doubt the dynamic solution is a good idea. See my comment on the other answer.