# How to build pivot table with dynamic data through linq using c#

Tags: c#, database, linq

I have got this datatable in my c# code:

| id | Employee | opid | opvalue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 11 |
| 1 | A | 2 | 12 |
| 2 | B | 2 | 12 |
| 3 | C | 1 | 11 |
| 3 | C | 2 | 12 |
| 3 | C | 3 | 13 |
| . |  |  |  |
| . |  |  |  |
| . |  |  |  |
| n | N | 1 | 11 |
| n | N | 2 | 12 |

And opid read from another table :

| id | opName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | opA |
| 2 | opB |
| . |  |
| . |  |
| . |  |
| n | opN |

Now I want to create another DataTable which would look like this:

| id | Employee | opA | opB | opC | ... | opN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 11 | 12 | null | ... |  |
| 2 | B | null | 12 | null | ... |  |
| 3 | C | 11 | 12 | 13 | ... |  |
| . |  |  |  |  | ... |  |
| . |  |  |  |  | ... |  |
| . |  |  |  |  | ... |  |
| n | N | 11 | 12 | null | ... |  |

Comment: pivoting on db level is easier, but check how to pivot in linq https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167304/is-it-possible-to-pivot-data-using-linq

Comment: I am glad that this matter is simple for you. I checked the links that exist in this field and because I did not find an answer, I asked the question. The point of this question is that the number of columns in the pivot table is not clear. If you pay attention to the question, you will understand this

Comment: so you can join tables than pivot. P.S. i gave you example how to pivot in linq, i guess you can google how to left join 2 tables in linq

Comment: if you need pivot N tables  check how to do it on sql side https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58970487/pivot-sql-table-to-n-columns

Comment: C# is a language of types - what types are involved here? Are you talking about actual `DataTable`s or some other types?